# Launchpad dailybuild source in subdirectory of branch

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, debian, bazaar, launchpad

I have a repo branch that i have mirrored in Launchpad that I am trying to setup a daily build. The problem is that the source directory of the package is a subdirectory in the branch.  When building locally it's no problem because I can just change to that directory. However with launchpad's bzr-builder it does everything from the top directory in the branch.

My current build recipe is:

```
# bzr-builder format 0.3 deb-version {debupstream}-{revno}-{revno:packaging}
lp:kegbot
nest-part packaging lp:~szechyjs/kegbot/kegbot_debian debian debian
```

Ideally I would use `lp:kegbot/pykeg` but this is not possible in bzr.

Is there a easy way I can build the package in the kegbot/pykeg directory, by setting it up in my recipe or some kind of source directory variable in the rules file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `bzr-builder` plugin currently doesn't support what you need.

In principle you could perhaps workaround it by making a branch of lp:pykeg that moves `pykeg/` to the root of the tree, and moves the old root to `ignored/`.  You could then add `merge workaround lp:`*`…/workaround-branch`* to your recipe.  Unfortunately pivoting the root of a tree like that isn't especially easy either.

It would be worth filing a bug on Launchpad and/or bzr-builder about this use-case.

Comment: i filed a bug on bzr-builder, it is being considered as a feature.